# Pyprocar spin texture plot error

Tags: vasp, pyprocar

I am trying to use Pyprocar to plot spin texture for studying rashba effect. Here is my input:

```
pyprocar.fermi2D(code='vasp', energy=1.0, spin_texture=True, no_arrow=True, arrow_projection='x', dir_name='./', color_bar=True, rotation=[90,1,0,0])
```

To plot spin texture, I also generated 2d k-mesh with Pyprocar:

```
Generated by PyProcar
100
Reciprocal
0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000 
0.0000000   0.0000000   0.0555556   1.0000000 
0.0000000   0.0000000   0.1111111   1.0000000 
0.0000000   0.0000000   0.1666667   1.0000000 
0.0000000   0.0000000   0.2222222   1.0000000 
0.0000000   0.0000000   0.2777778   1.0000000 
0.0000000   0.0000000   0.3333333   1.0000000 
0.0000000   0.0000000   0.3888889   1.0000000 
0.0000000   0.0000000   0.4444444   1.0000000 
0.0000000   0.0000000   0.5000000   1.0000000 
0.0555556   0.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000 
0.0555556   0.0000000   0.0555556   1.0000000 
0.0555556   0.0000000   0.1111111   1.0000000 
0.0555556   0.0000000   0.1666667   1.0000000 
0.0555556   0.0000000   0.2222222   1.0000000 
0.0555556   0.0000000   0.2777778   1.0000000 
0.0555556   0.0000000   0.3333333   1.0000000 
0.0555556   0.0000000   0.3888889   1.0000000 
0.0555556   0.0000000   0.4444444   1.0000000 
0.0555556   0.0000000   0.5000000   1.0000000 
0.1111111   0.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000 
0.1111111   0.0000000   0.0555556   1.0000000 
0.1111111   0.0000000   0.1111111   1.0000000 
0.1111111   0.0000000   0.1666667   1.0000000 
0.1111111   0.0000000   0.2222222   1.0000000 
0.1111111   0.0000000   0.2777778   1.0000000 
0.1111111   0.0000000   0.3333333   1.0000000 
0.1111111   0.0000000   0.3888889   1.0000000 
0.1111111   0.0000000   0.4444444   1.0000000 
0.1111111   0.0000000   0.5000000   1.0000000 
0.1666667   0.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000 
0.1666667   0.0000000   0.0555556   1.0000000 
0.1666667   0.0000000   0.1111111   1.0000000 
0.1666667   0.0000000   0.1666667   1.0000000 
0.1666667   0.0000000   0.2222222   1.0000000 
0.1666667   0.0000000   0.2777778   1.0000000 
0.1666667   0.0000000   0.3333333   1.0000000 
0.1666667   0.0000000   0.3888889   1.0000000 
0.1666667   0.0000000   0.4444444   1.0000000 
0.1666667   0.0000000   0.5000000   1.0000000 
0.2222222   0.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000 
0.2222222   0.0000000   0.0555556   1.0000000 
0.2222222   0.0000000   0.1111111   1.0000000 
0.2222222   0.0000000   0.1666667   1.0000000 
0.2222222   0.0000000   0.2222222   1.0000000 
0.2222222   0.0000000   0.2777778   1.0000000 
0.2222222   0.0000000   0.3333333   1.0000000 
0.2222222   0.0000000   0.3888889   1.0000000 
0.2222222   0.0000000   0.4444444   1.0000000 
0.2222222   0.0000000   0.5000000   1.0000000 
0.2777778   0.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000 
0.2777778   0.0000000   0.0555556   1.0000000 
0.2777778   0.0000000   0.1111111   1.0000000 
0.2777778   0.0000000   0.1666667   1.0000000 
0.2777778   0.0000000   0.2222222   1.0000000 
0.2777778   0.0000000   0.2777778   1.0000000 
0.2777778   0.0000000   0.3333333   1.0000000 
0.2777778   0.0000000   0.3888889   1.0000000 
0.2777778   0.0000000   0.4444444   1.0000000 
0.2777778   0.0000000   0.5000000   1.0000000 
0.3333333   0.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000 
0.3333333   0.0000000   0.0555556   1.0000000 
0.3333333   0.0000000   0.1111111   1.0000000 
0.3333333   0.0000000   0.1666667   1.0000000 
0.3333333   0.0000000   0.2222222   1.0000000 
0.3333333   0.0000000   0.2777778   1.0000000 
0.3333333   0.0000000   0.3333333   1.0000000 
0.3333333   0.0000000   0.3888889   1.0000000 
0.3333333   0.0000000   0.4444444   1.0000000 
0.3333333   0.0000000   0.5000000   1.0000000 
0.3888889   0.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000 
0.3888889   0.0000000   0.0555556   1.0000000 
0.3888889   0.0000000   0.1111111   1.0000000 
0.3888889   0.0000000   0.1666667   1.0000000 
0.3888889   0.0000000   0.2222222   1.0000000 
0.3888889   0.0000000   0.2777778   1.0000000 
0.3888889   0.0000000   0.3333333   1.0000000 
0.3888889   0.0000000   0.3888889   1.0000000 
0.3888889   0.0000000   0.4444444   1.0000000 
0.3888889   0.0000000   0.5000000   1.0000000 
0.4444444   0.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000 
0.4444444   0.0000000   0.0555556   1.0000000 
0.4444444   0.0000000   0.1111111   1.0000000 
0.4444444   0.0000000   0.1666667   1.0000000 
0.4444444   0.0000000   0.2222222   1.0000000 
0.4444444   0.0000000   0.2777778   1.0000000 
0.4444444   0.0000000   0.3333333   1.0000000 
0.4444444   0.0000000   0.3888889   1.0000000 
0.4444444   0.0000000   0.4444444   1.0000000 
0.4444444   0.0000000   0.5000000   1.0000000 
0.5000000   0.0000000   0.0000000   1.0000000 
0.5000000   0.0000000   0.0555556   1.0000000 
0.5000000   0.0000000   0.1111111   1.0000000 
0.5000000   0.0000000   0.1666667   1.0000000 
0.5000000   0.0000000   0.2222222   1.0000000 
0.5000000   0.0000000   0.2777778   1.0000000 
0.5000000   0.0000000   0.3333333   1.0000000 
0.5000000   0.0000000   0.3888889   1.0000000 
0.5000000   0.0000000   0.4444444   1.0000000 
0.5000000   0.0000000   0.5000000   1.0000000
```

2d plane is located at x-z plane which range from(0,0,0) to (0.5,0,0.5). Then I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/polyucmp/DATA/BIAN_Tieyuan/yinjun/plot_spin-new/n4-R-new/plot_spin.py", line 14, in <module>
    spin_plot=pyprocar.fermi2D(code='vasp', energy=1.5, spin_texture=True, no_arrow=True, arrow_projection='y', dirname=data_dir, exportplt=True, color_bar=True, rotation=[90,1,0,0])
  File "/media/polyucmp/DATA/BIAN_Tieyuan/software/anaconda3/envs/vasp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyprocar/scripts/scriptFermi2D.py", line 227, in fermi2D
    fs.spin_texture(sx=symm.sx, 
  File "/media/polyucmp/DATA/BIAN_Tieyuan/software/anaconda3/envs/vasp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyprocar/core/fermisurface.py", line 319, in spin_texture
    bnew.append(griddata((x, y), band, (xnew, ynew), method="cubic"))
  File "/media/polyucmp/DATA/BIAN_Tieyuan/software/anaconda3/envs/vasp/lib/python3.9/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/_ndgriddata.py", line 277, in griddata
    ip = CloughTocher2DInterpolator(points, values, fill_value=fill_value,
  File "interpnd.pyx", line 915, in scipy.interpolate.interpnd.CloughTocher2DInterpolator.__init__
  File "_qhull.pyx", line 1827, in scipy.spatial._qhull.Delaunay.__init__
  File "_qhull.pyx", line 353, in scipy.spatial._qhull._Qhull.__init__
scipy.spatial._qhull.QhullError: QH6154 Qhull precision error: Initial simplex is flat (facet 1 is coplanar with the interior point)

While executing:  | qhull d Qbb Q12 Qc Qz Qt
Options selected for Qhull 2019.1.r 2019/06/21:
  run-id 1834633720  delaunay  Qbbound-last  Q12-allow-wide  Qcoplanar-keep
  Qz-infinity-point  Qtriangulate  _pre-merge  _zero-centrum  Qinterior-keep
  Pgood  _max-width 0.35  Error-roundoff 4.9e-16  _one-merge 3.4e-15
  Visible-distance 9.8e-16  U-max-coplanar 9.8e-16  Width-outside 2e-15
  _wide-facet 5.9e-15  _maxoutside 3.9e-15

The input to qhull appears to be less than 3 dimensional, or a
computation has overflowed.

Qhull could not construct a clearly convex simplex from points:
- p1(v4): 0.039     0 0.0039
- p10(v3):  0.18     0  0.35
- p9(v2):  0.35     0  0.32
- p0(v1):     0     0     0

The center point is coplanar with a facet, or a vertex is coplanar
with a neighboring facet.  The maximum round off error for
computing distances is 4.9e-16.  The center point, facets and distances
to the center point are as follows:

center point   0.1417        0   0.1689

facet p10 p9 p0 distance=    0
facet p1 p9 p0 distance=    0
facet p1 p10 p0 distance=    0
facet p1 p10 p9 distance=    0

These points either have a maximum or minimum x-coordinate, or
they maximize the determinant for k coordinates.  Trial points
are first selected from points that maximize a coordinate.

The min and max coordinates for each dimension are:
  0:         0    0.3519  difference= 0.3519
  1:         0         0  difference=    0
  2:         0    0.3519  difference= 0.3519

If the input should be full dimensional, you have several options that
may determine an initial simplex:
  - use 'QJ'  to joggle the input and make it full dimensional
  - use 'QbB' to scale the points to the unit cube
  - use 'QR0' to randomly rotate the input for different maximum points
  - use 'Qs'  to search all points for the initial simplex
  - use 'En'  to specify a maximum roundoff error less than 4.9e-16.
  - trace execution with 'T3' to see the determinant for each point.

If the input is lower dimensional:
  - use 'QJ' to joggle the input and make it full dimensional
  - use 'Qbk:0Bk:0' to delete coordinate k from the input.  You should
    pick the coordinate with the least range.  The hull will have the
    correct topology.
  - determine the flat containing the points, rotate the points
    into a coordinate plane, and delete the other coordinates.
  - add one or more points to make the input full dimensional.
```

I cannot figure out the problem. What may cause this? Can someone help me? Thanks!

Comment: I gave my +1 long ago but have you figured this out now? Please update us! Are you still urgently or actively in need of an answer?